# Splitting multicolumn table

Tags: tables, multicolumn

I have a table such that;

```
\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[a4paper,onesided,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Çınar's emergent codes and corresponding themes}
\begin{tabular}{|m{9cm}|m{5cm}| }
\hline\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{RELEVANT CODES} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{THEME} \\ 
\hline
Graph representation (false assumption) & \\ 
Graph completion & \multirow{1}{*}{Interpretation of    } \\ 
Determining slope & \multirow{1}{*}{graph} \\
Determining values for horizontal and vertical axes & \\
\hline
Writing problem situation & \multirow{1}{*}{Making sense of model}  \\ 
Solve conflicts on variable- graph interaction by a model& \multirow{1}{*}{representation} \\ 
Writing reasonable real world situation & \\ 
\hline
IV $\rightarrow$ time, DV $\rightarrow$ velocity & \\ IV $\rightarrow$ time, DV $\rightarrow$ location & \\ 
IV $\rightarrow$ undetermined, DV $\rightarrow$ location & \multirow{3}{*}{Searching for} \\
IV $\rightarrow$ decide to change IV except "time"& \multirow{2}{*}{variable} \\
IV $\rightarrow$ temperature, DV $\rightarrow$ temperature & \\
IV $\rightarrow$ time, DV $\rightarrow$ location & \\
IV $\rightarrow$ time, DV $\rightarrow$ subjects completed during summer school & \\ \hline
IV $\rightarrow$ location, DV $\rightarrow$ time and looking their interaction & \multirow{3}{*}{Alignment of } \\ 
Manipulation of graph properties to fit graph to determined variables & \multirow{2}{*}{variable-graph }   \\ 
Finding conflict when matching variables on graph & \\ \hline

Converting graph to table & \multirow{1}{*}{Converting graph} \multirow{1}{*}{to table} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{center}      
\end{document}
```

I need to divide them into two parts since the table contains several rows and they did not fit in one page.

Comment: You might be interested in the `longtable` environment from the eponymous package that allows tables to use several pages.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: The text is very long. I tried to summarize it.

Comment: @leandriis: I think it's the environment that's eponymous of the package.

Comment: @Bernard: As I unfortunately do not know if the package author named the package or the environment first, this is very similar to the chicken or the egg causality dilemma to me. However, both share the same name, which is what I wanted to express in my comment.

Comment: An addditional comment/observation: Don't use "dumb quotes" , as in `"y"` -- the typeset output will be wrong. Instead, do use "smart" quotes, e.g., `\`\`y''`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following example, I have used the `longtable` environment in order to allow the table to be split onto several pages if it is too long to fit onto a single page. I have also made sure that the width of the table does not exceed the textwidth. I have therefor calculated the width of the second column relative to the current textwidth. Additionally, I have corrected the usage of `\multirow` in order to vertically align the text in the second column with respect to the corresponding entries in the first column. Lastly, I removed all vertical lines and replaced the horizontal lines with the rules from the `booktabs` package. (In order to make the table too long for one page, I have repeated some contents)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newlength{\mycolumnwidth}
\setlength{\mycolumnwidth}{\textwidth-9cm-4\tabcolsep}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{m{9cm}m{\mycolumnwidth} }
\caption{Chris's emergent codes and corresponding themes}\\
\toprule
 RELEVANT CODES &   THEME \\
\endfirsthead 
\caption{Chris's emergent codes and corresponding themes (continued)}\\
\toprule
 RELEVANT CODES &   THEME \\
\endhead 

\midrule
Graph representation (false assumption) & \multirow{4}{\mycolumnwidth}{Interpretation of graph}\\ 
Graph completion &  \\ 
Determining slope & \\
Determining values for horizontal and vertical axes & \\

\midrule

Writing problem situation & \multirow{4}{\mycolumnwidth}{Making sense of model representation}  \\ 
Solve conflicts on variable- graph interaction by a model&  \\ 
Writing reasonable real world situation & \\ 

\midrule

IV $\rightarrow$ time, DV $\rightarrow$ velocity & \multirow{8}{\mycolumnwidth}{Searching for variable}\\ IV $\rightarrow$ time, DV $\rightarrow$ location & \\ 
IV $\rightarrow$ undetermined, DV $\rightarrow$ location &  \\
IV $\rightarrow$ decide to change IV except "time"& \\
IV $\rightarrow$ temperature, DV $\rightarrow$ temperature & \\
IV $\rightarrow$ time, DV $\rightarrow$ location & \\
IV $\rightarrow$ time, DV $\rightarrow$ subjects completed during summer school & \\ 

\midrule

IV $\rightarrow$ location, DV $\rightarrow$ time and looking their interaction & \multirow{5}{\mycolumnwidth}{Alignment of variable-graph} \\ 
Manipulation of graph properties to fit graph to determined variables &   \\ 
Finding conflict when matching variables on graph & \\ 
\midrule

Converting graph to table & Converting graph to table \\

\midrule

Converting graph to model & Converting graph to model \\

\midrule

Interpreting the number on the table &  \multirow{4}{\mycolumnwidth}{Alignment of table and variables} \\ 
Looking for correlation between x and y values& \\ 
Looking for variable that gives "y" value & \\
IV $\rightarrow$ time, DV $\rightarrow$ location confusion  & \\ 

\midrule
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Converting graph to table & Converting graph to table \\

\midrule

Converting graph to model & Converting graph to model \\

\midrule

Interpreting the number on the table &  \multirow{4}{\mycolumnwidth}{Alignment of table and variables} \\ 
Looking for correlation between x and y values& \\ 
Looking for variable that gives "y" value & \\
IV $\rightarrow$ time, DV $\rightarrow$ location confusion  & \\ 
\bottomrule

\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It fits very well.