# split a long table

Tags: longtable, split

I have a table that is needed to be split since it does not fit one page. I can not manage to divide it, is there any way to accomplish this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[a4paper,onesided,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{table} [H]
\caption {Tarık's theme categories and their definition }
\begin{tabular}{|m{3cm}|m{4cm}|m{7cm}| }
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Theme}  &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Explanation} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Example} \\ \hline

Interpretation of graph & Determining the characterization of the graph based on information given in the explanation part  & T: I will get a parabolic shape when zooming out the graph since it intersects two points on x-axis. \\ \hline

Interpretation of function &    
Emphasizing quadratics functions and where it can be observed in daily life & T: Where can I find a quadratic function in real life? Physics come to my mind.  I remember that velocity and time have a quadratic relationship. For example, I remember $\dfrac{1}{2}at^2$. \smallskip \\ \hline

Make sense of model representation & Searching for meaning of modeling with mathematics &   T: What am I supposed to do here if I am required to write a model? \\ \hline

Searching for variable &    Looking for different possible variable options for given graph &   T: What about location-time graph? \newline
R: What do you mean? \newline
T: Well.. I can state one of my variable as time and look for change of location in graph. \\ \hline

Writing equation &  Writing equations that can represent the given graph    & R: If this is a graph looking downward, then its equation may be $-x^2+3$ \\ \hline 

Drawing a model &   Demonstrating his model by a simple drawing &  \medbreak \includegraphics[scale=0.9]{T_model1.png} \\ \hline 

Alignment of model-graph &  Checking whether written model matches with the given graphical representation & T:I summarized what I have done here. I modelled this graph as motion of ball thrown upward from a point 3 m above the ground with an initial velocity. In addition, this graph shows the change depending on the time. It will go upward and come down.  There are two moments that are same as the ground level and those are two points that intersect x-axis on the given graph. The y values would be zero there. \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't explain what is your problem nor you do any question. Please improve your question. Also, are you using `article` or `report`? Choose one.

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/436605/134144)? You can use the exact same approach (`longtable`) for this table as well.

Comment: The other table has multicolumns, I can not accomplish to adopt the previous version to this code.

Comment: It is obvious that this is much more easier to do it however I am pretty new to LateX and it is really difficult for me to understand it.

Comment: Then please show what you've tried so far. Helping you with a specific question/ seeing where the problem is, is much easier and you will benefit a lot more from it. Could you please also add the missing packages to your example? As it is, it does not compile.

Comment: @ZeynepP in the solution to your previous answer, the answer has any multicolumn. So I really don't understand why they are different.

Comment: I guess, I succeed it. However, this time the lines between columns shrink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `longtable` replaces both `table` and `tabular`, but adds `\endhead` after the `\caption`.  Also missing were `amsmath` and `graphicx`.  I replaced your image with `example-image`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,onesided,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|m{3cm}|m{4cm}|m{7cm}| }
\caption {Tarık's theme categories and their definition }
\endhead
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Theme}  &\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Explanation} & \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Example} \\ \hline

Interpretation of graph & Determining the characterization of the graph based on information given in the explanation part  & T: I will get a parabolic shape when zooming out the graph since it intersects two points on x-axis. \\ \hline

Interpretation of function &    
Emphasizing quadratics functions and where it can be observed in daily life & T: Where can I find a quadratic function in real life? Physics come to my mind.  I remember that velocity and time have a quadratic relationship. For example, I remember $\dfrac{1}{2}at^2$. \smallskip \\ \hline

Make sense of model representation & Searching for meaning of modeling with mathematics &   T: What am I supposed to do here if I am required to write a model? \\ \hline

Searching for variable &    Looking for different possible variable options for given graph &   T: What about location-time graph? \newline
R: What do you mean? \newline
T: Well.. I can state one of my variable as time and look for change of location in graph. \\ \hline

Writing equation &  Writing equations that can represent the given graph    & R: If this is a graph looking downward, then its equation may be $-x^2+3$ \\ \hline 

Drawing a model &   Demonstrating his model by a simple drawing &  \medbreak \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image} \\ \hline 

Alignment of model-graph &  Checking whether written model matches with the given graphical representation & T:I summarized what I have done here. I modelled this graph as motion of ball thrown upward from a point 3 m above the ground with an initial velocity. In addition, this graph shows the change depending on the time. It will go upward and come down.  There are two moments that are same as the ground level and those are two points that intersect x-axis on the given graph. The y values would be zero there. \\ \hline 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```